# How to remove ownerRef from kubernetes secret using kopf

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

can you please help me with the problem I'm facing? I use an kubernetes operator based on python and kopf for copying secrets from a namespace to one or more other namespaces, based on annotations. The code is working as expected, except when the secret has **ownerRef**. In that case it is deleted by garbage collector with reason **OwnerRefInvalidNamespace**

I was looking into solving this with kopf.remove_owner_reference, or kopf.adopt, but with no luck.
parse_target_namespaces just returns the list of target namespaces where the secret is to be copied.

```py
    @kopf.on.create('', 'v1', 'secrets', annotations={'synator/sync': 'yes'}, when=watch_namespace)
    @kopf.on.update('', 'v1', 'secrets', annotations={'synator/sync': 'yes'}, when=watch_namespace)
    def update_secret(body, meta, spec, status, old, new, diff, **kwargs):
        api = kubernetes.client.CoreV1Api()
        namespace_response = api.list_namespace()
        namespaces = [nsa.metadata.name for nsa in namespace_response.items]
        namespaces.remove(meta.namespace)

        secret = api.read_namespaced_secret(meta.name, meta.namespace)
        secret.metadata.annotations.pop('synator/sync')
        secret.metadata.resource_version = None
        secret.metadata.uid = None
        for ns in parse_target_namespaces(meta, namespaces):
            secret.metadata.namespace = ns
            # try to pull the Secret object then patch it, try creating it if we can't
            try:
                api.read_namespaced_secret(meta.name, ns)
                #kopf.remove_owner_reference(secret, owner=None)
                api.patch_namespaced_secret(meta.name, ns, secret)
            except kubernetes.client.rest.ApiException as e:
                print(e.args)
                #kopf.remove_owner_reference(secret, owner=None)
                #kopf.adopt(secret, strict=True, forced=True, nested='spec.template')
                api.create_namespaced_secret(ns, secret)
```

I was looking into solving this with kopf.remove_owner_reference, or kopf.adopt, but with no luck.
Please help if you can. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution was pretty simple... Removing reference from metadata body.

```
secret.metadata.owner_references = None
```